# Determine if the unit disc in the complex plan is star-shaped or not

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Let $D$ := {$ p ∈ \mathbb C $ | $ |p| \le 1$} . Is this set star-shaped?
>   If yes, to which center?

I have been given the following definition:

A domain $D$ is a star domain with centre $z_0$ if for each point $w ∈ D$ the entire line segment $[p_0, w]= \{wt + p_0(1-t) | t ∈ [0,1]\}$ lies within $D$.

How do I use this to answer the question?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your set is a circle. Thus convex and you can easily show that any convex set is star-shaped with respect to any center.

Let $D := \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \leq 1\}$ and $z_0 \in D$. Furthermore let $z \in D$. Consider the segment $[z_0,z]$. Let $t \in [0,1]$. Then we have $$|zt + z_0(1 - t)| \leq |z|t + |z_0|(1-t) \leq t + (1 - t) = 1$$ Hence $zt + z_0(1 - t) \in D$ for any $t \in [0,1]$ which means $$[z_0,z] \subseteq D$$

Comment: I'm still struggling with this can you explain further please

Comment: @user407151 Added the proof.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot

Comment: @user407151 You're welcome!