# Can a closed region of the complex plane be star shaped?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm working with the same definition of a star domain as the one referred to in this post: [Determine if the unit disc in the complex plan is star-shaped or not](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246286/determine-if-the-unit-disc-in-the-complex-plan-is-star-shaped-or-not).  I read elsewhere in my notes, though, that a domain is an open subset of the complex numbers.  Does that mean that closed discs cannot be star domains, even though they are simply connected sets?  I'm new to complex analysis, and am a little confused by this.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usual in Complex Analysis to deal only with functions whose domain is an open subset of $\Bbb C$ (that is, we only work with functions whose domain is an open set). So, if we *define* a domain as an open subset of $\Bbb C$, then yes, no closed disk is a domain, although it is star-shaped.

Comment: This makes it clear - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The use of "domain" in complex analysis is not the same as that in topology. The two concepts are independent, and a closed region can be a star domain.

Comment: So a closed region can be a star domain in topology, but not in complex analysis (if a domain is defined as being an open subset)?  Thank you!

Comment: @user604270 Yes. Mathematics is full of confusing terms.